# 3 by 2 sub plot having different yaxis and titles and same x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create 3 by 2 grid to plot six columns of dataframe each column in one subplot.
Each subplot should have different title. On xaxis i have index and yaxis is different.

Example dataframe i have created with dummy values.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Column 1':  [1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'Column 2': [10,20,30,40,50,60],
         'Column 3': [50,100,150,200,250,300],
        'Column 4':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'Column 5': [10,20,30,40,50,60],
        'Column 6': [50,100,150,200,250,300]
        }

Xnew = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Column 1','Column 2','Column 3','Column 4','Column 5','Column 6'])

print (Xnew)
```

I have tried below code. and i am getting six subplot of unequal size, color of line graph is same, and title isnt visible. graph of some subplot is truncated too.

```
fig = plt.figure() 

yaxis0 = Xnew['Column 1']
yaxis1 = Xnew['Column 2']
yaxis2 = Xnew['Column 3']
yaxis3 = Xnew['Column 4']
yaxis4 = Xnew['Column 5']
yaxis5 = Xnew['Column 6']

ax0 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1) 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2) 
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 1)
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 2) 

# Subplot 1: Box plot
yaxis0.plot(kind='line', ax=ax0) 
ax0.set_title('Quantity of Column 1 in compounds')
ax0.set_xlabel('ID')
ax0.set_ylabel('Column 1')

# Subplot 2: Line plot
yaxis1.plot(kind='line', ax=ax1) 
ax1.set_title('Quantity of Column 2 in compounds')
ax1.set_xlabel('ID')
ax1.set_ylabel('Column 2')

yaxis2.plot(kind='line', ax=ax2) 
ax2.set_title('Quantity of Column 3 in compounds')
ax2.set_xlabel('ID')
ax2.set_ylabel('Column 3')

# Subplot 2: Line plot
yaxis3.plot(kind='line', ax=ax3) 
ax3.set_title('Quantity of Column 4 in compounds')
ax3.set_xlabel('ID')
ax3.set_ylabel('Column 4')

yaxis4.plot(kind='line', ax=ax4) 
ax4.set_title('Quantity of Column 5 in compounds')
ax4.set_xlabel('ID')
ax4.set_ylabel('Column 5')

# Subplot 2: Line plot
yaxis5.plot(kind='line', ax=ax5) 
ax5.set_title('Quantity of Column 6 in compounds')
ax5.set_xlabel('ID')
ax5.set_ylabel('Column 6')


plt.show()
```

Dont understand whats wrong. Whats the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating the subplot grid `axes` with [**`plt.subplots()`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) and then iterating `axes[row][col]`:

```py
nrows, ncols = 3, 2
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(8,8))

for index, column in enumerate(Xnew.columns):
    row, col = index // ncols, index % ncols
    ax = axes[row][col]

    Xnew[column].plot(kind='line', ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f'Quantity of {column} in compounds')
    ax.set_xlabel('ID')
    ax.set_ylabel(column)
    
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: plt.subplots() grid]

---

Non-loop version:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(8,8))

yaxis0 = Xnew['Column 1']
yaxis1 = Xnew['Column 2']
yaxis2 = Xnew['Column 3']
yaxis3 = Xnew['Column 4']
yaxis4 = Xnew['Column 5']
yaxis5 = Xnew['Column 6']

# Subplot 1
ax0 = axes[0][0]
yaxis0.plot(kind='line', ax=ax0) 
ax0.set_title('Quantity of Column 1 in compounds')
ax0.set_xlabel('ID')
ax0.set_ylabel('Column 1')

# Subplot 2
ax1 = axes[0][1]
yaxis1.plot(kind='line', ax=ax1) 
ax1.set_title('Quantity of Column 2 in compounds')
ax1.set_xlabel('ID')
ax1.set_ylabel('Column 2')

# Subplot 3
ax2 = axes[1][0]
yaxis2.plot(kind='line', ax=ax2) 
ax2.set_title('Quantity of Column 3 in compounds')
ax2.set_xlabel('ID')
ax2.set_ylabel('Column 3')

# Subplot 4
ax3 = axes[1][1]
yaxis3.plot(kind='line', ax=ax3) 
ax3.set_title('Quantity of Column 4 in compounds')
ax3.set_xlabel('ID')
ax3.set_ylabel('Column 4')

# Subplot 5
ax4 = axes[2][0]
yaxis4.plot(kind='line', ax=ax4) 
ax4.set_title('Quantity of Column 5 in compounds')
ax4.set_xlabel('ID')
ax4.set_ylabel('Column 5')

# Subplot 6
ax5 = axes[2][1]
yaxis5.plot(kind='line', ax=ax5) 
ax5.set_title('Quantity of Column 6 in compounds')
ax5.set_xlabel('ID')
ax5.set_ylabel('Column 6')

plt.tight_layout()
```